# "ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list " how to fix this?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE employee  
(  
Boundry_number INT  , 
emp_ID INT , 
eName VARCHAR2(30) ,  
Nationality VARCHAR2(30), 
PRIMARY KEY (Boundry_number, emp_ID), 
FOREIGN KEY (Boundry_number) REFERENCES Efada (Boundry_number))




CREATE TABLE Efada (  
Sponser_number INT,  
Type_residence VARCHAR2(30),  
Boundry_number INT, 
PRIMARY KEY (Boundry_number))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First create **master** table, then its **detail**; otherwise, foreign key constraint from the detail table doesn't have anything to reference (as master doesn't exist yet) and Oracle raises an error.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Efada
  2  (
  3     Sponser_number   INT,
  4     Type_residence   VARCHAR2 (30),
  5     Boundry_number   INT,
  6     PRIMARY KEY (Boundry_number)
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE employee
  2  (
  3     Boundry_number   INT,
  4     emp_ID           INT,
  5     eName            VARCHAR2 (30),
  6     Nationality      VARCHAR2 (30),
  7     PRIMARY KEY (Boundry_number, emp_ID),
  8     FOREIGN KEY (Boundry_number) REFERENCES Efada (Boundry_number)
  9  );

Table created.
```